# CSS spain image effect not working in safari browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a logo which is just spinning in the center of the page. And it is working properly in all the browser except in the safari browser on Mac.

He only shows half of it and I don't know what the problem is.

Check these screenshots

[In all browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7O4v.png)

[This is how it is coming in mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxHq.jpg)

**This is my logo markup.**

```css
.loader .image-rotate-horizontal{
            float: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            margin-top: -60px;
            margin-left: -60px;
            -moz-animation: spin-horizontal 1s infinite linear;
            -o-animation: spin-horizontal 1s infinite linear;   
            -webkit-animation: spin-horizontal 1s infinite linear;
            animation: spin-horizontal 1s infinite linear;
            }

            @-moz-keyframes spin-horizontal {
            0% {
            -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            }

            100% {
            -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
            }

            @keyframes spin-horizontal {
            0% {
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
            }
            100% {
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
            }
            
            @-o-keyframes spin-horizontal {
            0% {
            -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            }
            100% {
            -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes spin-horizontal {
            0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            }
            100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes animationIncreaseMac {
              0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
              }
              100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
              }
            }

            .button{
            cursor: pointer;    
            }
```

```html
<div class="loader"><img src="image/logo.png" alt="logo" class="image-rotate-horizontal"></div>
```

Is there any help with that ?

***Thank you***

Comment: Any safari update?

Comment: sorry i am not getting. @headmax

Comment: browser and version using on mac ? you need to set it on your topic.

Comment: Safari browser and version is 10.1..2 @headmax

Comment: @Vandana Seems to be working fine in my mac in safari browser. Here i update one css property in your code and removed negative margin. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/06s0xb16/4/

Comment: @Vandana Try to use this http://jsfiddle.net/4404ftgb/ tested in safari

Comment: Thank u @AnmolSandal

Comment: Thank u @Mo'menMohamed